# C++ program compiling without functional header

Tags: c++, header-files

As per [CPP Doc](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/greater/), `std::greater` is defined in `<functional>` header but my C++ program using `std::greater` is compiling with TDM-GCC-64 5.1.0 and running with only the following includes :

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <unordered_map>
```

It could be because `<algorithm>` automatically includes `<functional>` but since this is not mentioned in the doc, I was wondering is there a way to know this before hand ?

Comment: No there is no way of knowing such implementation details because that's what they are, implementation details. If you want to be portable and conformant to the C++ standard you should always include the header files needed for the functions and classes you need.

Comment: I did not expect this to be implementation dependent. I was under the impression that the definition of headers would be standard and so would any implicit hierarchy in their imports.

Comment: iostream is the usual one, it slurps in a lot of headers by itself.  You can know the implementation details, just look in the header.  The risk is that the source file won't compile on another compiler.  No biggie, easy to fix of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close the topic, the conclusion is that this is implementation dependent and all the necessary headers should be included for portability.